# Adding CardView to Eclipse Luna's Palette

Tags: android, eclipse, android-cardview

I'd like to make `CardView` readily accessible to me every time I make/edit my Android projects in Eclipse Luna; as readily-available as `TextView`. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Very much appreciated, folks!